# Fn+F8 does not switch displays on a Dell E6410

Tags: 11.10, nvidia, display, dell

I recently upgraded to Oneric and found that <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> does not switch displays on Oneric, Dell E6410, Nvidia. I frequently run presentations and need to switch between projector and laptop with minimum fuss, so this key is important to me!

In Maverick, I managed to make it work using `acpi_osi=\\\"!Windows 2009\\\"` in grub (as described here: http://www.len.ro/2011/01/e6410-summary/). It's a bit shameful to go into a room of people, plug the laptop and wait 5 minutes to make the change using nvidia-settings. How can I make the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> work again?

After a bit of debuging with xev it seems that the acpi_osi has some effect but the videoswitch does not take place somewhere else even if `/var/log/XOrg.0.log` shows:

> [ 24182.812] (II) PM Event received: Capability Changed

Maybe there is some other place where the event is not handled correctly.

Comment: Try going to the system/power cog and clicking displays. From there you can switch your displays quickly.

Comment: William, I think this does not work if using the Nvidia driver; in that case you have to use nvidia-settings. disper and the disper-indicator could be a viable workaround, that's what I do.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I gave up and decided to adopt the simpler solution of using disper.

```
apt-add-repository ppa:disper-dev/ppa
apt-get update
apt-get install disper
```

and then

**disper -c** to switch to external monitor and **disper -s** to return to main screen. I also configured a shortcut in xfce which I now use to map p to disper -c

Answer (score 1):

Better solution for me seems to be to switch external display on/off using `nvidia-settings`, where it is possible to detect resolution of external display and switch the TwinView  feature on and off (as well as other helpful configuration options).

Answer (score 0):

http://ninetynine.be/blog/2010/05/quick-workaround-for-missing-switch-display-key-or-lcdcrt-key-on-ubuntu/

This post worked for me on a Dell Precision M6600 Ubuntu 14.04. Fn+F8 was broken

Answer (score -2):

Did it work in Windows? It may be that you are using the wrong key. Also, try using other keys (eg Fn+F5, Fn+F9, etc)

Comment: its clear that the user knows what key to use and they were working before the upgrade.